# Trying to create an associative array PHP

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter

I have the following array.  What I'm trying to do is get each element under  "bill_ids", use the ID (e.g. "hjres61-114") to make another call and then retitle the 0 under "bill_ids" to the ID and then include another array under that element.

[image: array]

Here's what I have and it's giving me this error..

> Message: Illegal offset type

```
        $floor_updates = $this->congress->floor_updates($params); 

        foreach ($floor_updates as $update) {

            if ($update['bill_ids']) {

                foreach ($update['bill_ids'] as $bill => $bill_id) {
                    $billInfo = $this->bill->billSearch(['bill_id' => $bill_id]);

                    $floor_updates[$update]['bill_ids'][$bill][0] = $billInfo;
                }

            }
        }
```

I'm terrible with php arrays and any guidance would be greatly appreciated..

Comment: `$update['bill_ids']` seems to suggest `$update` is an array, but here: `$floor_updates[$update]` you're using the array as key (so it'll be converted to a string, saying _"Array"_)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you actually want to do is the following:

First, capture the array index of each of our update elements. We can simply do that by passing in `$array_index => $update`.

```
foreach ($floor_updates as $array_index => $update)
```

Now, we can access the `$update` array by `$floor_updates[$array_index]`.

```
$floor_updates[$array_index]['bill_ids'][$bill] = $billInfo;
```

In the above, there's no reason to access the `0th` element of the array as the `$bill` actaully contains reference to the index of each key value pair, so we can simply just reference `[$bill]` to get access to the array.